# processing nested headers using c pre processor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am using C pre-processor `cpp` for `file.c` It gives me desired output if all the headers are included in `file.c` are available in same folder. If one header `h1` includes another header `h2` it does not pre-process the header `h2` and throws error saying:

> h2 No such file or directory.

How to solve this?

command:

```
cpp file.c
```

Comment: cpp -IpathToh2 file.c

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `-I` to tell the pre-processor where to look for files to be `#include`d.

```
cpp -I/some/path -I/another/searchpath/ file.c
```